# Fragment Transaction between 2 FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments

i implement side navigation in my code and i used this librairy

https://github.com/korovyansk/android-fb-like-slideout-navigation

the list side extends FragmentActivity and the Main side extends FragmentActivity (see picture). 
[image]

when i click in item of the list i want the main fragment replaced by another fragment

so it there a way to  do transaction  fragment in the Main FragmentActivity  from the list FragmentActivity  what i can add to this code  to make the transaction in Main not in List

```
FragmentTransaction ft =getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.fragment, newFragment);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
if(aFragment!=null) {
    ft.detach(aFragment);//*ft.hide(aFragment);
    ft.commit();
} 
ft.attach(bFragment);//*ft.show(bFragment);
ft.commit();
```

`*` *use one of these*

Comment: this not work between 2  fragment activity i tried to add interface class and implement method in the main fragment activity it also not work

Answer (score 0):

i resolved it by using   ft.commitAllowingStateLoss(); it resolve the exception : Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState